# Appended strings in message body not being sent in email using SMTPClient() and StringBuilder()

Tags: c#, .net, email, stringbuilder, smtpclient

First and foremost I am very new to C# and am sure most of my code could be cleaned up so please don't suggest it unless you are also offering help with my issue.

I am sending an email via `SmtpClient()`. I am trying to build the body of the email using strings which are returned from functions in loops. My issue is that the string for the body isn't building how I thought it should.

Currently, I am creating a new `StringBuilder()` with some default text in it. I am then running some functions and trying to add the results to the `StringBuilder()` object via `StringBuilder.AppendLine()`.

Here is (some of) my code:

```c#
// Setup SMTP Client for sending mail updates
//-----------------------------------
String from_addr_text = "<removed>";
String to_addr_text = "<removed>";
String msg_subject = "Updates to USPTO searches";
StringBuilder msg_body = new StringBuilder("The following searches have received updated results:" + Environment.NewLine);
SmtpClient AlertMail = new SmtpClient
{
    Port = 587,
    Host = "<removed>",
    EnableSsl = true,
    Timeout = 10000,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("<removed>", "<removed>")
};
MailMessage update = new MailMessage(from_addr_text, to_addr_text, msg_subject, msg_body.ToString())
{
    BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8,
    IsBodyHtml = false,
    DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure
};

            ...

// Process data from api for Assignor
//-----------------------------------
bool isUpdated = false;
foreach (String url in searchesByAssignorUSPTO)
{
    try
    {
        String longName = <removed>); 
        String name = <removed>;
        String thisHash = await GetSearchData(url, name, "Assignor");
        if (DoesHashExist(thisHash))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(thisHash + " already exists. No update to " + name + " search.");
        }
        else
        {
        Debug.WriteLine(thisHash + " does not exist. There is an update to " + name + " search.");
        isUpdated = true;
        msg_body.AppendLine(name + " as " + "Assignor" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("something is broken with ASSIGNOR search dummy!");
    }
}
// Process data from api for Assignee
foreach (String url in searchesByAssigneeUSPTO)
{
    try
    {
        String longName = <removed>;
        String name = <removed>;
        String thisHash = await GetSearchData(url, name, "Assignee");
        if (DoesHashExist(thisHash))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(thisHash + " already exists. No update to " + name + " search.");
        }
        else 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(thisHash + " does not exist. There is an update to " + name + " search.");
            isUpdated = true;
            msg_body.AppendLine(name + " as " + "Assignee" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("something is broken with ASSIGNEE search dummy!");
    }
}
// Send email is search results are updated
if (isUpdated)
{
    AlertMail.Send(update);
    Debug.WriteLine(msg_body.ToString());
}
```

When the program runs and there are results returned from the loops, `msg_body` is printed to the output window correctly but, when the email is received the body is only: "The following searches have received updated results:".

I have tried:

- changing the value of `isBodyHtml` to `true` and used `<br />`
  instead of `Environment.NewLine`.
- adding `\n` to end of stringing and removing `Environment.NewLine`.
- changing `msg_body` to type `String` and concatenating results to `msg_body` using `=+`.
- using the `Append()` method instead of `AppendLine()`.

Here is a snip of the output window:
[image: Output window showing strings appended to SB]

Comment: try to create this `MailMessage update`  in very end, when you will add to `msg_body` variable everything what needed.

Comment: @tym32167 Perfection! Thanks bud! So simple a fix and it makes sense when I sit back and think about it.

Comment: np, glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to watch the assignment of variables in your code.  When you assign `msg_body` to the `update` MailMessage object, it's only inputting the one line mentioned that is being returned in the email and doesn't include the information generated by the API.

Try moving the intialization of your `SmtpClient` and `MailMessage` variables to right before the `if (isUpdated)` block and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

per @tym32167, I needed to move the instantiation of `MailMessage()` to AFTER my loops and functions were completed. I was creating the object before the `AppendLines()` methods were called and therefore they weren't being included.